# move to new page with controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

help me

viewhome.php

```
<li class="main_nav_item">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('contact');?>">contact</a></li>
```

contact(controller)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contact extends CI_Controller {

   public function index()
   { 
       $this->load->view('viewcontact.php');
   }
}
?>
```

config
    `$config['index_page'] = '';`

autoload
     `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','file','form');`

but always
Object not found!
help me, please

I can open viewhome, but when I click CONTACT, object not found.

My base URL config =`localhost/Final`

Comment: You showed a view called `viewhome.php`, but your controller is using `viewcontact.php` - is that intentional?

Comment: Is your base_url set in the config file?

Comment: If controller not found its either to wrong filename or routing issue .. what is the name of the contact controller file itself?

Comment: name of the contact controller is contact.php @SherifSalah

Comment: I set base_url config = localhost/Final (link localhost) @NiallLonergan

Comment: My home page is viewhome, in viewhome have href to viewcontact. But controller not found @Don'tPanic

Comment: Controller file name must begin with a capital letter so make sure its `Contact.php`

Comment: not working:( @SherifSalah

Comment: Don't worry it will .. try to set the route manually in `routes.php`

Comment: what should I do with routes.php? my routes.php just    $route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = ' '; @SherifSalah

Comment: Add a new line at the end like this `$route['contact'] = 'contact';` .. and by the way are you sure you add `.htaccess' correctly?

Comment: i try add anew line, buta not working again:( my .htasccess RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L] @SherifSalah

Comment: Are you using CI2 or CI3? .. and can you post a pic of your folder structure showing Controller, Views and FCPATH?

Comment: i using CI2 @SherifSalah , okey wait

Comment: Btw, your base_url should be like this `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/my_app/';` .. make sure you add `http://`

Comment: look my next question @SherifSalah

Comment: my base url add http but.... notworking again @SherifSalah

Comment: show me your folder structure

Comment: wait @SherifSalah , ican't post my picture, you have email?

Comment: It was a problem with redirecting, there was no .htaccess file in FCPATH.

Comment: What codeigniter version are you using? In your tags you added a couple different version. This can be misleading

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as

in viewhome.php

```
<li class="main_nav_item">
<a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/contact';?>">contact</a></li>
```

in application/config/routes.php add

```
$route['contact'] = 'Contact';
```